# Where is source of Bukkit.getServer().getOfflinePlayer(name)?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

In Minecraft bukkit, Where is source of `Bukkit.getServer().getOfflinePlayer(name)`?

I have found the source of Bukkit.java:
https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/Bukkit.java#L437

However this just forwards to
https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit/blob/f210234e59275330f83b994e199c76f6abd41ee7/src/main/java/org/bukkit/Server.java#L614

I want to know, which class('s) implement(s) `Server` and where is the 'final' code of `getOfflinePlayer(name)`?

PS: I am also happy with `getOfflinePlayer(uuid)`

Answer (score 0):

The Bukkit project has been taken over by Spigot years ago. The Bukkit API is fully open source and can be found [here](https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/projects/SPIGOT/repos/bukkit/browse), but keep in mind that the server platform specific implementation is in either [CraftBukkit](https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/projects/SPIGOT/repos/craftbukkit/browse) or [Spigot](https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/projects/SPIGOT/repos/spigot/browse). Both the CraftBukkit and Spigot repository only contain the changes made to the decompiled vanilla client due to legal reasons. The easiest way to get the sources of these projects on your computer is by running [BuildTools](https://hub.spigotmc.org/jenkins/job/BuildTools/).